# Dumpsys meminfo: kB or KB?

Tags: android, adb, units-of-measurement

Is the memory returned by adb shell dumsys meminfo in kB or KB?

where:

```
kB = 1000 bytes    
KB = 1024 bytes
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's KB (1024 bytes), or kibibytes (KiB), contrary to the kB notation in their printfs which is supposed to mean 1000 bytes as you noted.

Here's how I know. On my Linux box, if I do `free -b`,

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    67459153920 60865880064 6593273856  307834880 1373028352 40107618304
```

So look at the total value of 67459153920. That's in bytes (-b). Now if I look at meminfo,

```
MemTotal:       65878080 kB
```

and 67459153920 / 1024 = 65878080, so that value is in KB or aka KiB (1024 bytes).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Note that I tested this on my Linux desktop because Android Linux doesn't happen to include the `free` command, but `dumpsys meminfo` is just reporting the results of `cat /proc/meminfo` which is implemented at the Linux kernel level of Android [`fs/proc/meminfo.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.4/fs/proc/meminfo.c).

Comment: the way *you know* - you just look at the source code

Comment: "the way you know - you just look at the source code"- you should definitely post that in your own answer, as opposed to criticizing mine.